# How to delete multiple lines in a python console window?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a text-adventure, which should have a more or less complex fight system.  To create such, I decided to generate a `16x16` tile battlefield, which will be represented by ASCII-characters.  But, because a fight may take more than turn, I don't want to reprint the battlefield multiple times, but delete the "old" one and print the new situation to the same place.  But I suppose that it won't work with `sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stdout.flush()` since there have to be removed multiple lines.  So my question is: how do I accomplish my goal?  At the moment I open a new console window, where everything is reprinted, which is ahem... not very elegant.

Another problem would be the cross-platform use of the programm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `curses` module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html).

Comment: Ah, I knew I forgot something: the solution is supposed to work on Windows and Unix, so curses won't work, I suppose.

Comment: I believe there is a windows compatible curses module, although it isn't in the standard library.

Comment: I haven't tried this one myself, but here is a curses compiled for windows: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses  Otherwise you could use colorama on Windows (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama).  I've done a light wrapper that you may or may not find helpful: https://github.com/thebjorn/doscmd-screen

Comment: Thanks, I already found this link, I am currently trieing to get it to work.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm doing a very similar thing.